# how group graph pattern work in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl

First of all, i don't know if this really called group graph pattern or not. Anyway,

Look at this query please

```
select ?x  ?y where {
  {?x rdf:type rs:Recommendable}
 union
  {?xd rs:doesntexist ?y}
}
```

there is **no** `rs:doesntexist` but with `union` i got the results only from the first sub graph which is `{?x rdf:type rs:Recommendable}`

but if i remove the union, so the query will be:

```
select ?x  ?y where {
  {?x rdf:type rs:Recommendable}

  {?xd rs:doesntexist ?y}
}
```

I get empty results, may I ask you please who this work?

and the weird thing to me that this query

```
select ?x  ?y where {
  {?x rdf:type rs:Recommendable}.{}

}
```

works perfectly so the one before it doesnt?

#### Update

I think the union is like optional, I'm not sure. is it right please? (and by optional i didn't mean the optional from sparql, but i meant like when extracting the data from a union two graphs, its optional that two of them have data but if one of them is empty, we'll have the data from the other)

Comment: UNION and OPTIONAL are different.  Read up on them and try them out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ?x  ?y where {
  {?x rdf:type rs:Recommendable}

  {?xd rs:doesntexist ?y}
}
```

is like (not identical) to:

```
select ?x  ?y where {
  ?x rdf:type rs:Recommendable
  ?x rs:doesntexist ?y
}
```

Both patterns must match. If there is no rs:doesntexist the whole thing fails.

```
{}
```

matches all (zero) its patterns so it always works.

Comment: Hm, could you explain in practical terms how **(not identical)** are the two queries above?

Comment: (1) If the SPARQL entailment is supported, then the separate {} are evaluated for entailment separately. (2) if you use labels bnodes in queries there restrictions cross {} (3) if you add FILTERS, then they do not apply outside the {} they are written in. (4) its a different abstract syntax tree.  All minor points but which may come into play later.

Comment: @AndyS maybe this could be interesting for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102841/sparql-dividing-a-bgp-into-multiple-groups